# how to make circle?

Tags: c

Problem is, I am not getting a proper circle. For example, if I enter cordinates:9,8 and radius:8 ... I only get very few points.. Can somebody please guide me in how to obtain a complete circle, what is wrong in this code? We cannot use any built in function..

Comment: Even if this worked it would be possibly the most inefficient way to draw a circle, I suggest you read about polar-coordinates on wiki then try again.

Comment: Also, consider formatting your code and having a reasonable user name.

Comment: C is not C++. If you're not writing C++, don't add it to your tag list.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect

`if(sqrt(pow(i,2)+ pow(j,2))== radius)`

It's very rare that these two values will be **exactly** equal. Instead you should make a test to see if the two numbers are roughly equal. Like this for instance

`if (fabs(sqrt(pow(i,2)+ pow(j,2)) - radius) <= 0.001)`

This tests if `sqrt(pow(i,2)+ pow(j,2))` and `radius` are within 0.001 of each other. You might need to change the value of 0.001 to something else. It depends on your co-ordinate system.

Comment: the absolute value is not needed, `x ^ 2 + y ^ 2` will never be greater than `r ^ 2`, it's sufficient to check for the sum to be greater than `r - epsilon`.

Comment: @H2CO3 In the OP's loop x^2 + y^2 is most definitely greater than r^2 on occasion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

Nice thing about it that it uses only integer arithmetic - so it is both fast and exact.

Answer (score 0):

> what is wrong in this code?

Here you are:

```
if (sqrt(pow(i, 2) + pow(j, 2)) == radius)
```

You should not compare floating-point numbers using `==`, it won't work as expected. You should check instead if it's **close to** the radius:

```
if (sqrt(pow(i, 2) + pow(j, 2)) >= radius * 0.95)
```

for example.